# A-frame cursor timeout not working

Tags: aframe

I have code which, when you look at an element, it moves. I achieve this using a-cursor with `fuse="true"`. I want to make the fuseTimeout 100 milliseconds and I tried adding the following to the `<a-cursor>` element:

- `cursor="fuseTimeout: 100"`
- `timeout="100"`
- `fuseTimeout="100"`

Here is the full code: https://jsfiddle.net/be1pgjyv/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `fuse-timeout="100"`. The docs are off, will fix.